# How to use pstricks package within beamer? I know the pure English typseting method using pstricks in beamer, but failed xelatex pstricks beamer

Tags: beamer, xetex, errors, pstricks

In order to display simple figure, I began to learn `pstricks` package. I copied a piece of sample code to a `beamer` file. When I compile it, something goes wrong. How can I fix it? Process `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` does not work,neither with `xelatex`, who can help me?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[square]
%\setbeamerfont{title}{WenQuanYi Zen Hei Mono}
%\setbeamercolor{title}{green}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}

\title{moumou专题}
\author{author}
\institute{moumou@gmail.com}
\date{2013-07-22}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
%\tiny
\scriptsize
在平面直角坐标系$xoy$中,点B与点$\text{A}(-1,1)$关于原点O对称,P是动点,且直线AP与BP的斜率之积等于$-\dfrac{1}{3}$.\\
%\begin{enumerate}
%    \item 求动点P的轨迹方程;
%    \item 设直线AP和BP分别与直线$x=3$交于点M,N,问:是否存在点P使得$\bigtriangleup\text{PAB}$与$\bigtriangleup\text{PMN}$的面积相等?若存在,求出点P的坐标;若不存在,说明理由.
(I)求动点P的轨迹方程;\\
(II)设直线AP和BP分别与直线$x=3$交于点M,N,问:是否存在点P使得$\bigtriangleup\text{PAB}$与$\bigtriangleup\text{PMN}$的面积相等?若存在,求出点P的坐标;若不存在,说明理由.
%\end{enumerate}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (0,2) -- (2,0)-- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (0,2) -- (2,0)-- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:2]
\draw[thick,color=gray,step=.5cm,
dashed] (-0.5,-.5) grid (3,3);
\draw[->] (-1,0) -- (3.5,0)
node[below right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,3.5)
node[left] {$y$};
\draw plot[id=x] function{x*x};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(5,2)
\psline[linecolor=blue](1,1)(2,2)(3,1)(4,2)(5,1)
\psline[linearc=0.5,linecolor=red](1,1)(2,2)(3,1)(4,2)(5,1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{fram}


\end{document}
```

Here is the compiling information screenshot:
[image: compiling information]

Comment: Have you tried adding the `fragile` option to your frames?

Comment: Whether I add the fragile it seems no difference for the below Herbert's smaple code.Thank you anyway.It works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Do not use  two extensions for the data file. Use something like
  `ps-beamer-x.table`
- Use `[t,fragile]` as optional argument for the frame with `enumerate`

my output with `xelatex':

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[square]
%\setbeamerfont{title}{WenQuanYi Zen Hei Mono}
%\setbeamercolor{title}{green}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}

\title{moumou专题}
\author{author}
\institute{moumou@gmail.com}
\date{2013-07-22}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t,fragile]
%\tiny
\scriptsize
在平面直角坐标系$xoy$中,点B与点$\text{A}(-1,1)$关于原点O对称,P是动点,且直线AP与BP的斜率之积等于$-\dfrac{1}{3}$.\\
\begin{enumerate}
    \item 求动点P的轨迹方程;
    \item 设直线AP和BP分别与直线$x=3$交于点M,N,问:是否存在点P使得$\bigtriangleup\text{PAB}$与$\bigtriangleup\text{PMN}$的面积相等?若存在,求出点P的坐标;若不存在,说明理由.
(I)求动点P的轨迹方程;\\
(II)设直线AP和BP分别与直线$x=3$交于点M,N,问:是否存在点P使得$\bigtriangleup\text{PAB}$与$\bigtriangleup\text{PMN}$的面积相等?若存在,求出点P的坐标;若不存在,说明理由.
\end{enumerate}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (0,2) -- (2,0)-- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (0,2) -- (2,0)-- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:2]
\draw[thick,color=gray,step=.5cm,
dashed] (-0.5,-.5) grid (3,3);
\draw[->] (-1,0) -- (3.5,0)
node[below right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,3.5)
node[left] {$y$};
\draw plot[id=x] function{x*x};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(5,2)
\psline[linecolor=blue](1,1)(2,2)(3,1)(4,2)(5,1)
\psline[linearc=0.5,linecolor=red](1,1)(2,2)(3,1)(4,2)(5,1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you please give much more details?I am new to xelatex,I even do not know ps-beamer-x.table,and how to use [t,fragile]?I always learn xelatex by reading sample code.Would you please show me some code?

Comment: Instead of `\begin{frame}[t]` use `\begin{frame}[t,fragile]`. Your logfile shows that a data file wasn't found (see above)! And that one has two dots in the filename which maybe another problem.

Comment: Thanks for you quick respond!I modified the code,and I do not see the difference after adding "fragile" to that frame,I think there maybe something else goes wrong.I know how to draw figure using pure English beamer file.But When I typeset Chinses and English the compilation informations come out.

Comment: I have no problem with your example. See my edit

Comment: Thank you very much.I commented the item environment.It also works,I prefer to display a plain page,I do not like the default marker.There are lots of details for me to learn ,such as the inner,outer,color themes.